# QuarkXPress crashes when opening one project

Tags: macos, crash, quarkxpress

**I am having a problem with QuarkXPress 9.5.4.0 on an iMac running Mac OS X 10.11.6.**

The problem is that whenever I try to open a particular project QuarkXPress crashes. I would normally have a backup, but I’ve only been working on this project since yesterday and haven’t got one.

**Is there anything I can do that will avoid losing everything I’ve done up to this point?**

Please tell me if this is the wrong site for this question. I flipped a coin to pick between this one and the graphic design one. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QuarkXPress has a built-in process for validating project files that you can use to try and repair any file inconsistencies. To do this follow these steps:

1. Launch QuarkXPress
2. Go to **File > Open** (or press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>)
3. Navigate to and **select** the project file you’re having a problem with, but **do not** click on Open yet
4. Now press and hold <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd>
5. While still holding these keys down, click on the <kbd>Open</kbd> button

You *should* find that the project opens successfully without crashing QXP, but you may also find that your content has reflowed differently to how you had it originally. Now you should create a new version of the project by dragging the thumbnails from this one to a new one. See below for how to do this:

1. Still in QXP, create a new project
2. Make sure the new project has the same layout and setup (such as *facing pages* or not) and also has the same number of pages
3. In each of the projects, go to **View > Thumbnails**
4. In each of the projects, go to **Window > Tile** and select either *horizontal* or *vertical*
5. Now, in your original project click the first page and hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while you also click on the last page
6. Now drag the pages to your new project
7. Save your new project using a different name
8. Close both projects
9. Now try to reopen the new project you saved at Step 7

At this point, the best case scenario is that your new project opens without crashing QXP. If so, make a backup of it before working to get your design back to how you wanted.

If you can’t open the new project, then it’s likely the problem was a particular image, font, etc. If this is the case, follow Steps 1 to 9 again except at Steps 5 and 6 only drag one page across to the new project. If that works, then you know that page was fine, so repeat the steps to copy one page at a time and, as you do that, save your file using a different name each time. This way you’ll hopefully identify the page (or pages) that was causing the problem.

I know there’s quite a bit in this answer to follow, so if you have any problems or I’ve not been very clear, let me know and I’ll try to help you further.

Comment: Wow!! This worked a treat and I swear you saved me like 8 or 9 hrs of work! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! :)

Comment: My pleasure! :) As an aside, QXP also offers native support for automatically saving backups of your projects. Go to QuarkXPress > Preferences... and select Open and Save in the left-hand pane. This will give you access to Auto Save and Auto Backup options. You may want to consider taking advantage of these. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I use QXP almost daily and didn't know this trick. Thank you for sharing! :)